# Asynchronous API Get Response Not Being Stored in UseState Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, async-await

**Context**: I am retrieving data about tutors from an API endpoint using Axios GET request. It is intended to be processed and sent to other components within the application.

**Problem**: I am currently using an useEffect() hook in my main App() function to initiate the GET request. I am storing the response onto a useState() hook for access at a later point in the code. While I can see the API response by logging within the useEffect code segment, I am not able to access the response oustide of it. This data state variable isn't populated with the JSON.

**My Understanding**: I suspect that the state variables are being accessed before it is populated by the API response in the useEffect() hook code segment. Or it could be that setTutors() isn't working for some reason.

**Code**:

```
function App() {
    const [ searchTerm, setSearchTerm ] = useState("");
    const [ sorted, setSorted] = useState(false);

    const [ data, setTutors ] = useState([]);


    useEffect( () => {
        const retrieveData = async () => {
            const resp = await axios.get('API URL Call');
            console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(resp.data.body));
            setTutors(JSON.stringify(resp.data.body)); //NOT Storing Value into Data
        }

        retrieveData();
    });

    

    function handleSearchTerm(event)  {
        setSearchTerm(event.target.value)
    }

    function handleSortByName() {
        // sort array ascending or descending by first name
        if (!sorted) {
            setTutors(data.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1));
            setSorted(true);
        } else {
            setTutors(data.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? -1 : 1));
            setSorted(false);
        }
    }

    function handleSortByDept() {
        // sort array ascending or descending by dept name
        if (!sorted) {
            setTutors(data.sort((a, b) => (a.department > b.department) ? 1 : -1));
            setSorted(true);
        } else {
            setTutors(data.sort((a, b) => (a.department > b.department) ? -1 : 1));
            setSorted(false);
        }
    }

    const filteredTutors = data.filter(tutor => tutor.first_name.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchTerm.toLowerCase()));
    //TODO: search by category
    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <Layout>
                <h1 className="title text-5xl text-gray-800 mt-16">Tutor Directory</h1>
                <p className="mb-16 text-md">Search for an tutor or sort by Name or Category.</p>
                {/*the handleSearchTerm method and searchTerm state get passed down to the Navigation component via props with the onSearch and searchTerm props*/}
                <Navigation
                    onSearch={handleSearchTerm}
                    searchTerm={searchTerm}
                    handleSortByName={handleSortByName}
                    handleSortByDept={handleSortByDept}
                />
                {/* the employees array gets the filteredEmployees data via the data prop */}
                <TutorCardList data={filteredTutors}/>
                {/* <GetRequestHooks /> */}
                <Footer/>
            </Layout>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

**Errors**:
(1) [Dependent code on the state variable not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYz1o.png)
(2) [Empty Data on Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njbzx.png)

I referred to other StackOverFlow questions, didn't find it much helpful so decided to post my own.

Comment: `setTutors(JSON.stringify(resp.data.body))`: why are you stringifying your data before adding it to the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not convert the response JSON to string before setting in the state.

```
setTutors(JSON.stringify(resp.data.body));
```

to

```
setTutors(resp.data.body);
```

Also, you should not modify the origin state while sorting the data

```
setTutors(data.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1));
```

to

```
setTutors(prev => [...prev].sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1));
```